# Calculate angle to translate the circle at the 90 degree on an arc

Tags: geometry, angle

I have one design like this:[image]

Now i want to calculate angle between the clicked circle and the position at 90 degrees on outer arc. How do i calculate that ?

I have angle of outer circles in radians.

Comment: Emm... Subtract angle of circle and 90 degrees(Pi/2) ?

Comment: Sorry didn't get you.

Comment: To calculate difference between two angles, one should subtract them. If you mean something other, reformulate the question.

Comment: Suppose its the point with angle around 300. Now if i subtract them it would give me 210 angle to be translated but thats not the case. That will require 90 degrees plus the difference between 210 and 300.

Comment: Shortest arc angle: `d = Abs(a - b); if (d > 180) then d = 360 - d`